# PHP 3 dimensional Array to HTML TABLE

Tags: php, html, arrays, loops, html-table

If I have this as a three dimensional array:

```
(int) Year 1 => array(
    'Department 1' => array(
        'Sales' => '12345',
        'Revenue' => '12345',
        'total' => '12345'
    ),
    'Department 2' => array(
        'Sales' => '12345',
        'Revenue' => '12345',
        'total' => '12345'
    ),
),
(int) Year 2 => array(
    'Department 1' => array(
        'Sales' => '12345',
        'Revenue' => '12345',
        'total' => '12345'
    ),
    'Department 2' => array(
        'Sales' => '12345',
        'Revenue' => '12345',
        'total' => '12345'
    ),

)
```

How would I display this in a HTML Table. With Years as the Header. Departments on the left side at the head of each row. ANd Sales, Rev, and totals in separate columns within the year column.

The output should look like

```
Department_______YEAR1_________Year2

Department 1  |Sales,Reveue |Sales,Reveue
Department 2  |Sales,Reveue |Sales,Reveue
```

Comment: pls include what should be the output

Comment: specify the main array that contains year1 and year2

Comment: So what have you tried? We are not your personal scripting army.

Answer (score -1):

First you must make a table and `TH` outside the loop

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>Department</th>
<th>Year 1</th>
<th>Year 2</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<?php

foreach ($1stvalue as $first => $2ndvalue ) {
    foreach ($2ndvalue as $second => $3rdvalue) {
        foreach ($3rdvalue as $third) {   
            echo "<td>".$first."</td>"."<td>".$second."</td>"."<td>".$third."</td>"."</tr>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

you need to foreach loop each dimension and echo it when you got it all

Comment: This will create a column for every value in the array. That's not what OP wants.